# PyDev Google App не запускается правильно, выдает: “Could not read search indexes from…”

Tags: python, eclipse, google-app-engine

Я написал *PyDev google application* по примеру из книги "Programming Google App Engine" (автор – Dan Sanderson) - глава 2, страница 25, "Developing a Python App", не выполнил только "Caching with memcache" part, но там и без этого создается рабочее приложение. Приложение работало правильно (как сервер), после чего я функцией `fopen()` попытался считать html-страницу и передать ее как аргумент для `self.response.out.write()`, не зная, работает ли это, но вместо какого-либо считывания localhost стал возвращать просто результат последнего работающего приложения (ответ другого приложения, которое правильно работало до того, как я написал это приложение).

И теперь во всех проектах-серверах такого типа мне выдает такое сообщение:

> WARNING 2016-05-08 20:34:13,348 simple_search_stub.py:1146] Could not read search indexes from
>   c:\users\max\appdata\local\temp\appengine.flotplot1\search_indexes

(Ниже - сообщения о том, что сервер запущен, хотя localhost:8080 не выдает то, что должен выдать для этого сервера.)

Откуда вообще появились эти поисковые индексы и как их прочесть, и надо ли это вообще? Или как вообще исправить это? Этого файла, адрес которого пишут, там нет, так что полагаю, что индексы нельзя считать, потому что нет файла с этими индексами, а его нет непонятно почему, но это только мои догадки.